# Add Space to Pagination Hyperlinks

Tags: css

I am trying to add spaces to pagination Numbers

my php looks like this

```
    echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
    echo "<a style=text-decoration:none href='dashboard.php?page=".($page-1)."'             class='button'>Previous</a>"; 

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
    echo "<a style=text-decoration:none href='dashboard.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
    };  

    echo "<a style=text-decoration:none href='dashboard.php?page=".($page+1)."' class='button'>NEXT</a>";
    echo "</ul>";
```

And the output looks somewhat like this

```
Previous12345678NEXT
```

How do i add spaces?

Comment: On your style add `'padding-left: 5px;'` like: `style='text-decoration:none; padding-left: 5px'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
    echo "<a style=text-decoration:none href='dashboard.php?page=".($page-1)."'             class='button'>Previous</a>"; 
echo ' ';

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
    echo "<a style=text-decoration:none href='dashboard.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
echo ' '; 
    };  

    echo "<a style=text-decoration:none href='dashboard.php?page=".($page+1)."' class='button'>NEXT</a>";
    echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
<?php
echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
echo "<a style=text-decoration:none href='dashboard.php?page=".($page-1)."' class='button'>Previous </a>"; 

for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {  
    echo "<a style=text-decoration:none href='dashboard.php?page=".$i."'>".$i." </a>";
};  

echo "<a style=text-decoration:none href='dashboard.php?page=".($page+1)."' class='button'>NEXT</a>";
echo "</ul>"; 
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

if In website use bootstrap then add pull-left and pull-right class in a tag for example :

```
echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
    echo "<a style="text-decoration:none" href='dashboard.php?page=".($page-1)."'             class='button pull-left'>Previous</a>"; 

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
    echo "<a style=text-decoration:none href='dashboard.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
    };  

    echo "<a style="text-decoration:none" href='dashboard.php?page=".($page+1)."' class='button pull-right'>NEXT</a>";
    echo "</ul>";
```

---

### **if you dont have bootstrap then use this code**

```
echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
    echo "<a style="text-decoration:none; float:left" href='dashboard.php?page=".($page-1)."'             class='button'>Previous</a>"; 

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
    echo "<a style=text-decoration:none href='dashboard.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
    };  

    echo "<a style="text-decoration:none; float:right" href='dashboard.php?page=".($page+1)."' class='button '>NEXT</a>";
    echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: your code is not correctly using quote marks and would cause errors in php as a result